# SDL2 - Camera only scrolls in x direction, but not y direction

Tags: camera, sdl2

I'm following along with the LazyFoo tutorial to create the basis for a simple arcade space shooter. I'm trying to get the sprite moving through the map while being tracked by the camera. The code I have works in the x direction but doesn't scroll/follow in the y direction. I can't figure out why because the code for both directions is the same.

Here's what I have, the camera function is at the bottom (line 300ish) in the main function.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

SDL_DisplayMode current;


const int LEVEL_WIDTH = 1280;
const int LEVEL_HEIGHT = 960;
int SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000;
int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1000;

SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;

SDL_Surface* gScreenSurface = NULL;

SDL_Texture* ship = NULL;

SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;

//Texture wrapper class
class LTexture
{
    public:
        //Initializes variables
        LTexture();
        
        //Deallocates memory
        ~LTexture();

        //Loads image at specified path
        bool loadFromFile( std::string path );

        //Deallocates texture
        void free();

        //Renders texture at given point
        void render( int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip = NULL, double angle = 0.0, SDL_Point* center = NULL, SDL_RendererFlip = SDL_FLIP_NONE );

        //Gets image dimensions
        int getWidth();
        int getHeight();
        void setWidth( int width );
        void setHeight( int height );

        private:
        
        //The actual hardware texture
        
        SDL_Texture* mTexture;
        
        //Image dimensions                                                                  
        int mWidth;
        int mHeight;
};

LTexture::LTexture() {

    mTexture = NULL;
    mWidth = 0;
    mHeight = 0;

}

LTexture::~LTexture() {
    free();
}

bool LTexture::loadFromFile( std::string path ) {

    free();

    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;

    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load( path.c_str() );
//  SDL_SetColorKey( loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB( loadedSurface->format, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

    newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( gRenderer, loadedSurface);

    mWidth = loadedSurface->w;
    mHeight = loadedSurface->h;

    SDL_FreeSurface( loadedSurface );

    mTexture = newTexture;
    return mTexture != NULL;
}

void LTexture::free() {

    if (mTexture != NULL) {
        SDL_DestroyTexture( mTexture );
        mTexture = NULL;
        mWidth = 0;
        mHeight = 0;
    }
}

void LTexture::render( int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip, double angle, SDL_Point* center, SDL_RendererFlip flip ) {
    
    SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, mWidth, mHeight };

    if ( clip != NULL ) {
        renderQuad.h = clip->h;
        renderQuad.w = clip->w;
    }

    SDL_RenderCopyEx( gRenderer, mTexture, clip, &renderQuad, angle, center, flip );
}

int LTexture::getWidth() {
    return mWidth;
}

int LTexture::getHeight() {
    return mHeight;
}

void LTexture::setWidth( int width ) {
    mWidth = width;
}

void LTexture::setHeight( int height ) {
    mHeight = height;
}

class Ship {

    public:
        // Ship dimensions
        const static int SHIP_HEIGHT = 100;
        const static int SHIP_WIDTH = 100;

        // Ship maximum velocity
        static const int SHIP_VELOCITY = 10;
        
        Ship();

        void handleEvent( SDL_Event &e );
        
        int getVelY();
        int getVelX();
        int getPosX();
        int getPosY();

        void move();

        void render( int camX, int camY );
    
    private:
        int mPosX, mPosY;
        int mVelX, mVelY;


};

LTexture shipTexture;
LTexture backgroundTexture;

Ship::Ship() {
    
    mPosX = 0;
    mPosY = 0;
    mVelX = 0;
    mVelY = 0;
}

int Ship::getVelY() {
    return mVelY;
}

int Ship::getVelX() {
    return mVelX;
}

void Ship::handleEvent( SDL_Event &e ) {

    if ( e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && e.key.repeat == 0 ) {
        
        switch (e.key.keysym.sym) {
            case SDLK_UP: mVelY -= SHIP_VELOCITY; break;
            case SDLK_DOWN: mVelY += SHIP_VELOCITY; break;
            case SDLK_LEFT: mVelX -= SHIP_VELOCITY; break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT: mVelX += SHIP_VELOCITY; break;
        }
    }

    else if ( e.type == SDL_KEYUP && e.key.repeat == 0 ) {

        switch (e.key.keysym.sym) {
            case SDLK_UP: mVelY += SHIP_VELOCITY; break;
            case SDLK_DOWN: mVelY -= SHIP_VELOCITY; break;
            case SDLK_LEFT: mVelX += SHIP_VELOCITY; break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT: mVelX -= SHIP_VELOCITY; break;
        }
    }
}

void Ship::move() {
    
    mPosX += mVelX;

    if ( mPosX < 0 || mPosX + SHIP_WIDTH > LEVEL_WIDTH ) {
        mPosX -= mVelX;
    }
    
    mPosY += mVelY;

    if ( mPosY < 0 || mPosY + SHIP_HEIGHT > LEVEL_HEIGHT ) {
        mPosY -= mVelY;
    }

}

void Ship::render( int camX, int camY ) {
    
    double angle;
    
    if ( mVelX > 0 )
        angle = 90.0;
    if ( mVelX < 0 )
        angle = 270.0;
    if ( mVelY > 0 )
        angle = 180.0;
    if ( mVelY < 0 )
        angle = 0.0;

    shipTexture.render( mPosX - camX, mPosY - camY, NULL, angle, NULL );

}

int Ship::getPosX() {
    return mPosX;
}

int Ship::getPosY() {
    return mPosY;
}

void init() {
    
    // Load window and associates surface
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow ( "Video Game v1.0", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer ( gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );
    // Enable PNG loading
    int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
    IMG_Init( imgFlags );
    
    // Format screen size
    SDL_DisplayMode current;
    SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode(0, &current );
    SCREEN_WIDTH = current.w;
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = current.h;
    SDL_Log("Display #%d: current display mode is %dx%dpx @ %dhz.", 0, current.w, current.h, current.refresh_rate);

}

void loadMedia() {

    shipTexture.loadFromFile( "8.png" );
    backgroundTexture.loadFromFile( "509906.png" );
    backgroundTexture.setWidth( SCREEN_WIDTH );
    backgroundTexture.setHeight( SCREEN_HEIGHT );
}

void close() {

    shipTexture.free();

    SDL_DestroyWindow( gWindow );
    gWindow = NULL;
    
    SDL_DestroyRenderer( gRenderer );
    gRenderer = NULL;

    SDL_Quit();
    IMG_Quit();
    
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] ) {
    
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event e;
    Ship ship;
    SDL_Rect camera = { 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT };
    init();
    loadMedia();

    while( !quit ) {
    
        while ( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) !=0 ) {
            if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ) {
                quit = true;
            }
            ship.handleEvent( e );
        }
        
        ship.move();

        camera.x = ( ship.getPosX() + Ship::SHIP_WIDTH / 2 ) - SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
        camera.y = ( ship.getPosY() + Ship::SHIP_HEIGHT / 2 ) - SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
        
        if ( camera.x < 0 )
            camera.x = 0;
        if ( camera.y < 0 )
            camera.y = 0;
        if ( camera.x > LEVEL_WIDTH - camera.w )
            camera.x = LEVEL_WIDTH - camera.w;
        if ( camera.y > LEVEL_HEIGHT - camera.h )
            camera.y = LEVEL_HEIGHT - camera.h;

        // Clear the screen
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF );
        SDL_RenderClear( gRenderer );
        
        backgroundTexture.render( 0, 0, &camera );
        ship.render( camera.x, camera.y );
        
        // Update screen
        SDL_RenderPresent( gRenderer );
    
    }

    close();

    return 0;
}





```
````

Comment: What did you do to debug your code? Did you try to print the behaviour of your variables on the console and see why it doesn't change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

```
LEVEL_HEIGHT = 960
camera.h = SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1000
```

And the code

```
if ( camera.y > LEVEL_HEIGHT - camera.h )
```

We can deduce that

```
range_of_action = LEVEL_HEIGHT - camera.h = 960 - 1000 = -40
```

We can conclude that the camera will always be at -40.

Your level is smaller than the field where you can scroll your camera.

To fix this, give more room for your camera to move, increase the size of your level.